# It cant loop other polls out. It just can show the first id of the polls

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

It always come out with one polls only. Although i have different polls saved in database. It always can show the first id of the database.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="pollFrm">
                    <?php
                    //include and initialize Poll class 
                    include 'Poll.class.php';
                    $poll = new Poll;

                    //get poll and options data
                    $pollResult= $poll->getPolls();
                        ?>
            <div class="pollContent">
            <?php echo !empty($statusMsg)?'<p class="stmsg">'.$statusMsg.'</p>':''; ?>
            <form action="" method="post" name="pollFrm">
            <h3><?php echo $pollResult['poll']['subject']; ?></h3>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach($pollResult['name'] as $opt){
                    echo '<li><input type="radio" name="voteOpt" value="'.$opt['id'].'" >'.$opt['name'].'</li>';
                } ?>
            </ul>
            <input type="hidden" name="pollID" value="<?php echo $pollResult['poll']['id']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="voteSubmit" class="button" value="Vote">
            <a href="results.php?pollID=<?php echo $pollResult['poll']['id']; ?>">Results</a>
            </form>
        </div>



    </form>
```

This is the function to get polls. I have try to delete the single. but it cant works.

```
 public function getPolls($pollType){
        $pollData = array();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->pollTbl." WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY created DESC";
        $pollResult = $this->getQuery($sql, $pollType);
        if(!empty($pollResult)){
            if($pollType == 'single'){
                $pollData['poll'] = $pollResult;
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->optTbl." WHERE poll_id = ".$pollResult['id']." AND status = '1'";
                $optionResult = $this->getQuery($sql2);
                $pollData['name'] = $optionResult;
            }else{
                $i = 0;
                foreach($pollResult as $prow){
                    $pollData[$i]['poll'] = $prow;
                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->optTbl." WHERE poll_id = ".$prow['id']." AND status = '1'";
                    $optionResult = $this->getQuery($sql2);
                    $pollData[$i]['name'] = $optionResult;
                }
            }
        }
        return !empty($pollData)?$pollData:false;
    }
```

/*
     * Runs query to the database
     * @param string SQL
     * @param string count, single, all
     */

```
private function getQuery($sql,$returnType = ''){
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($result){
        switch($returnType){
            case 'count':
                $data = $result->num_rows;
                break;
            case 'single':
                $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
                break;
            default:
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        $data[] = $row;
                    }
        }
    }
    return !empty($data)?$data:false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function getPolls has a default parameter of `$pollType = 'single'` passing nothing through to the function will result it resolving to the default of 'single'.

As that parameter is being passed down to getQuery function it's always only going to get one. I would suggest removing the default parameter entirely and changing the method to:

```
public function getPolls($pollType){
```

Comment: The error show: Undefined variable: poll
and Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPolls() on null in

Comment: Right do you see how the 'single' is being passed down to the getQuery function? I'd suggest you remove the default parameter completely.

Comment: Sorry, i am very new to this. Do i still need to remove the  if($pollType == 'single') ? Because it is giving me this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Comment: That's fine. No in the second snippet you provided. Remove the `= 'single'` from the parameter in brackets when you declare the method. See my updated answer :)

Comment: Ya i have updated. it giving me the Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Comment: @TomyHoon can you update your post with what the code now looks like? It sounds like you've deleted one too many brackets?

Comment: ok. Updated. I dont think i had delete too many. I just delete what you told me to.

Comment: But now you've deleted your default case from the switch? You previously had a while loop in there no? You need to add that back in. And revert the `$pollResult= $poll->getPolls('all the polls');` back to `$pollResult = $this->getQuery($sql, $pollType);`

Comment: I have put it back and replace to $pollResult = $this->getQuery($sql, $pollType); but it give this error Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Poll::getPolls(), 0 passed in @redreddington